# DataGridView To Excel With Colored Cells in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I looked a lots of example and demo but I could not to it.

I'm trying to convert datagridview to excel with background color .
i can only datagridview to excel but  without  background  color. i want export  excel with background color .
this my code .

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class view_all
    Dim con1 As SqlConnection 'cun concation
    Dim con As String ' string coonction 
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Dim tables As DataTableCollection
    Dim source1 As New BindingSource
    Dim APP As New Excel.Application
    Dim worksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim workbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim view As DataView



    Private Sub view_all_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim obj As New config
        con1 = New SqlConnection
        con1 = obj.getcontion()
        con1.Open()
        MessageBox.Show("Open Stock Limit ", "Open", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        da = New SqlDataAdapter("select * from item", con1)
        ds = New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "item")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
        DataGridView1.DataMember = "item"

        tables = ds.Tables
        view = New DataView(tables(0))
        source1.DataSource = view
        DataGridView1.DataSource = view
        DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False

        DataGridView1.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Item Id"
        DataGridView1.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Item Name"
        DataGridView1.Columns(2).HeaderText = "Item Number"
        DataGridView1.Columns(3).HeaderText = "GRN Number"
        DataGridView1.Columns(4).HeaderText = "Item Qty "
        DataGridView1.Columns(5).HeaderText = "Item Max"
        DataGridView1.Columns(6).HeaderText = "Item min"



    End Sub


    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting

        For i As Integer = 0 To Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim A As Integer = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value
            Dim c As String = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value
            Dim aa As Double ' string double herawanawa
            Dim cc As Double ' string double harawabanwa 
            aa = CDbl(Val(A))
            cc = CDbl(Val(c))

            If aa < cc Then
                Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red

            Else
                Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            End If
        Next



    End Sub


    '***************** export  excel *****************************
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Save.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Enter file name")
            Return
        End If


        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
        Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

        Dim i As Int16, j As Int16

        xlApp = New Excel.Application
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")




        For x = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(0 + 1, x + 1) = _
            DataGridView1.Columns(x).HeaderText
        Next

        For i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
            For j = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
                xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = _
                DataGridView1(j, i).Value.ToString()
            Next
        Next




                Dim path As String


                path = "C:\vb\" + TextBox1.Text.Trim + ".xls"

                If (path = TextBox1.Text) Then

                    MsgBox(" no ")
                    Return

                End If





                xlWorkBook.SaveAs(path, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, _
                 Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue)
                xlWorkBook.Close(True, misValue, misValue)
                xlApp.Quit()
                'MsgBox("misValue")
                MsgBox(path)
                releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)
                releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
                releaseObject(xlApp)

                MessageBox.Show("File completed to  save in your path")
    End Sub
    Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
        Try
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
            obj = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            obj = Nothing
            MessageBox.Show("Exception Occured while releasing object " + ex.ToString())
        Finally
            GC.Collect()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This is easier with an excel file template. Create an excel template. Set conditional formatting of background based on values of your other cells. When exporting, copy the template to a temp folder, open it, add your data, then save it to the folder and filename supplied by the user

Answer (score 0):

You need something along the lines of

```
Dim formatRange As Excel.Range
formatRange = worksheet.Range("A1", "A3")
formatRange.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red)
```

Just change the range in the brackets to match your range (You can also repeat the second and third lines to cover all different ranges and colors if you need to.

Hope this helps - Find more formatting options [here](http://vb.net-informations.com/excel-2007/vb.net_excel_page_format.htm).

Comment: i want color change dynamically . i already add condition change color. in datagridview    works is .ok but after  export  excel  row color did not show

Comment: @Duminda Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: Mr David ..datagridview   row color change dynamically    . a i want to export dynamically    change row color color export excel